# WebSocket client in C and win32 for Windows 7

Tags: c, winapi, windows-7, websocket, winhttp

I'm trying to figure out a way to implement a sample WebSocketClient in C using win32 APIs. I need it to communicate with a HTML+JS WebSocket server.

I see that most of the WebSocket specific APIs are supported only Windows 8 and above.
Like in [WinHttpWebSocketCompleteUpgrade function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707326%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Is my understanding incorrect?
Any guidance, if the approach is feasible, would be of much help.

Answer (score 0):

There is another Windows API for WebSockets called [WebSocket Protocol Component API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/websock/web-socket-protocol-component-api-portal). Microsoft has also provided a [sample code on Github](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/Websocket) which is a good starting point.